# I want to detect whether the right or left mouse button is down during a mousemove event

Tags: javascript, html, mousemove

I am using HTML5 and want to know if the right mouse button or left mouse button is held down during a mouse move. The right mouse button has event.button = 2 for the right button. The left button has event.button = 0. During the mousemove, event.button = 0 always. I have supplied some sample code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>demo on detecting mouse buttons</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<style>
#mycanvas{ border-style:solid; width:400px; height:400px; border-width:2px;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function detectDown(event)
{
var string = "Mouse Down, event.button = " +event.button;
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0,0,300,20);
context.fillText(string,0,10);
}

function detectMove(event)
{
var string = "Mouse Move, event.button = " +event.button;
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0,30,300,20);
context.fillText(string,0,40);
}

function detectUp(event)
{
var string = "Mouse Up, event.button = " +event.button;
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0,60,300,20);
context.fillText(string,0,70);
}
</script>

</head>

<!-- -->

<body>

<canvas id="mycanvas"onmousedown="detectDown(event)" onmouseup="detectUp(event)" onmousemove="detectMove(event)" >
</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might find jsfiddle.com useful for these sorts of tests and demos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse move event is necessarily button-agnostic.  It reports mouse *movement*, regardless of whether buttons are pressed or not.  You need to create a flag on `mousedown` that tracks which button is down; reset it on `mouseup`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => console.log(`mousedown: ${(e.buttons | e.button) === 1} when mousemove`));
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 2px dashed #a10000;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>mousemove here</div>
```

*Notice: when you want to run the code below IE8, use `attachEvent` to bind `mousemove`.*